# Don't update realmResult and not set TextView

Tags: java, android, realm

I have 4 classes. I got some data from the JSON and wrote the realm. After that, in FilmFeature class, I insert some new values to realm but realmResult don't update and TextView comes to null.

Before this class, We have some information on RealmResult but this information not to "Type" or "imdbID"

FilmFeature Class:

```
JSONArray array1 = jsonObject2.getJSONArray("Search");
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length(); i++) {

    final JSONObject film_ozel = array1.getJSONObject(i);

    if(baslik_bilgisi.equals(film_ozel.getString("Title"))) {
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                film film_ozellik = realm.createObject(film.class);
                try {
                    film_ozellik.setType(film_ozel.getString("Type"));
                    film_ozellik.setImdbID(film_ozel.getString("imdbID"));
                    realm.insertOrUpdate(film_ozellik);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

}
realmResult = realm.where(film.class).findAll();

tür.setText(realmResult.get(position).getType());
imdb.setText(realmResult.get(position).getImdbID());
```

Comment: You need to use a RealmChangeListener. The transaction is async.

Comment: yea i fixed it thank you